# How to get separator b/w UITabBarItems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want a separator in UItabBarItems as show in the below image.

[image]

How I could add the small separator lines b/w the tab items?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if you add background of tab items.you can add image or subview for making background.
You can make programmatically a background for UITabBar:

```
#define SEPARATOR_WIDTH 0.4f
#define SEPARATOR_COLOR [UIColor whiteColor]

- (void) setupTabBarSeparators {
    CGFloat itemWidth = floor(self.tabBar.frame.size.width/self.tabBar.items.count);

    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
    for (int i=0; i<self.tabBar.items.count - 1; i++) {
        UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(itemWidth * (i +1) - SEPARATOR_WIDTH/2, 0, SEPARATOR_WIDTH, self.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
        [separator setBackgroundColor:SEPARATOR_COLOR];
        [bgView addSubview:separator];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgView.bounds.size);
    [bgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *tabBarBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
}
```

Comment: I am asking for the bottom tab bar controller and want to add separator b/w tab items like you can see the separator line b/w blue and green tabbaritem

Comment: @SukhdeepSinghKalra it will works for bottom tabbar. Did you try ?